# Merge data.frame by Date (year and month)

Tags: r, date, dataframe, merge

## 1st Case

I have got two data.frames as follow:

```
df1 = read.table(text = 'Date  ID
1980-12-01  2
1982-11-01  1
1990-01-01  6
1993-07-01  9', header = TRUE)

df2 = read.table(text = 'Date  Var
1980-12-17  8
1982-11-07  9
1990-01-19  10
1993-07-20  22', header = TRUE)
```

I need to merge df1 with df2 by the column Date but by only considering the Year and Month, also because otherwise the merge does not work (because the Days are different).

My output should be like this:

```
Date    ID  Var
1980-12  2    8
1982-11  1    9
1990-01  6   10
1993-07  9   22
```

I considered to remove the Days in the Date columns but I would like to know if there is a quicker way to do this. I also checked and it seems that no one asked this question before.

Thanks

#

UPDATE

## 2nd Case

As suggested in the comments, what if I have got multiple observations in the same Year and Month in one data.frame?

e.g.

```
df1 = read.table(text = 'Date  ID #as 1st Case
1980-12-01  2
1982-11-01  1
1990-01-01  6
1993-07-01  9', header = TRUE)

df3 = read.table(text = 'Date  Var
    1980-12-17  8
    1980-12-29  4
    1980-12-30  1
    1982-11-07  9
    1982-11-12  1
    1990-01-19  10
    1990-01-22  21
    1993-07-20  22
    1993-07-26  12', header = TRUE)
```

My new output should be:

```
Date   Var    ID
1980-12  8     2
1980-12  4     2
1980-12  1     2
1982-11  9     1
1982-11  1     1
1990-01  10    6
1990-01  21    6
1993-07  22    9
1993-07  12    9
```

#

UPDATE

## 3rd Case

What if I have got multiple observations in the same Year and Month in both the data.frames?

```
df4 = read.table(text = 'Date  ID 
    1980-12-01  1
    1980-12-01  2
    1982-11-01  3
    1982-11-01  4
    1990-01-01  5
    1990-01-01  6
    1993-07-01  7
    1993-07-01  8', header = TRUE)

df3 = read.table(text = 'Date  Var      #as 2nd Case
    1980-12-17  8
    1980-12-29  4
    1980-12-30  1
    1982-11-07  9
    1982-11-12  1
    1990-01-19  10
    1990-01-22  21
    1993-07-20  22
    1993-07-26  12', header = TRUE)
```

The new output should be:

```
    Date       Var  ID
    1980-12-17   8   1
    1980-12-17   8   2
    1980-12-29   4   1
    1980-12-29   4   2
    1980-12-30   1   1
    1980-12-30   1   2
    1982-11-07   9   3
    1982-11-07   9   4
    1982-11-12   1   3
    1982-11-12   1   4
    1990-01-19   10  5
    1990-01-19   10  6
    1990-01-22   21  5
    1990-01-22   21  6
    1993-07-20   22  7
    1993-07-20   22  8
    1993-07-26   12  7
    1993-07-26   12  8
```

Comment: First of all, +1 for putting reproducible datas and expected output ;)

Comment: what if you have multiple observations from the same month?

Comment: I updated my question. this is actually my final aim. thanks for point this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We convert the 'Date' to `Date` class, `format` to year-month format in both the dataset and `merge` it together.

```
merge(transform(df1, Date = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")), 
             transform(df2, Date = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")))
#     Date ID Var
#1 1980-12  2   8
#2 1982-11  1   9
#3 1990-01  6  10
#4 1993-07  9  22
```

Or if there are many datasets, place it in a `list` and do the transform and merge

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(...), 
    lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:2)), transform, Date = format(as.Date(Date), "%Y-%m")))
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, could you please have a look at my update? or I will be forced to remove the answer acceptance. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

You need to format the date into month and year format. then you do a regular merge.

```
df1$my=format(as.Date(df1$Date), "%Y-%m")
df2$my=format(as.Date(df2$Date), "%Y-%m")
merge(df1,df2, by='my')
```

For multiple observation across same year and month, this would still work.

```
df1$my=format(as.Date(df1$Date), "%Y-%m")
df3$my=format(as.Date(df3$Date), "%Y-%m")
merge(df1,df3, by='my')
      my     Date.x ID     Date.y Var
1 1980-12 1980-12-01  2 1980-12-17   8
2 1980-12 1980-12-01  2 1980-12-29   4
3 1980-12 1980-12-01  2 1980-12-30   1
4 1982-11 1982-11-01  1 1982-11-07   9
5 1982-11 1982-11-01  1 1982-11-12   1
6 1990-01 1990-01-01  6 1990-01-19  10
7 1990-01 1990-01-01  6 1990-01-22  21
8 1993-07 1993-07-01  9 1993-07-20  22
9 1993-07 1993-07-01  9 1993-07-26  12
```

For update 3, one can use

```
merge(df4,df3, by='my', all = T)
```

Comment: You are right, the page didn't update, you posted around 20 or 30 secs before

Comment: Thank you for the comments and glad to know that you got inspiration from my posts.

Comment: Hi @ChirayuChamoli, could you please have a look at my update? this is actually what I really need to do. Thanks.

Comment: that's because there are no multiple observations per month in `df1`.